# Centre multiple elements, when the amount of elements may change

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

So in a project I am working on, I have the following code:

```
foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
{
    <div class="col-sm-2 DANNYSNEWCLASS">
        <label class="PreviousAnswerLbl">
            @if (answer == Model.PreviousAnswer)
                {
                     <input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" checked="checked" /><span>@answer</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" /><span>@answer</span>
                }
        </label>
    </div>
}
```

and the number of elements here can change anywhere from 2 to 5, so how do I do some CSS/bootstrap trickery to make it so that the radio buttons are all centred, when currently they all seem to float to the left. All this is already inside a `<div class="container">` and `<div class="row"` and all of that bootstrap stuff.

I want it so that, for example, if there are 5 labels, then the middle of the 3rd `label` is in the middle of this whole div with 2 labels on either side etc, as well as when there are only 2 labels, there is one on the left side of the screen, and one on the right, preferably without too big of a gap. Hopefully that makes sense, let me know if there is any more clarification needed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Its just a little bit of calculations required to decide on how many `col-sm-*` space to allot to each `div`. So here is a little trick. First get the number to decide on the each col width

```
@{
   var colWidth = 12 / @Model.Answers.Count(); 
 }
```

since bootstrap has 12 columned layout.

Then in your for loop you can do this..

```
  foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
  {
    <div class="col-sm-"+ @colWidth +" DANNYSNEWCLASS">
       .... 
       ....
    </div>
  }
```

**Note:** if your count is 5 then the `colWidth` will be 2. that means total of only 10 columns will be occupied. So that might leave out some space on to the right. For this we can use `col-sm-offset-1` which will give a offset of 1 column on left and now we will have 1 column on right. so all the divs will be centered.

So add this to your **First Div**

```
<div class="col-sm-"+ @colWidth +" DANNYSNEWCLASS "+ @Model.Answers.Count() == 5 ? "col-sm-offset-1":"" +"">
```

Comment: Yeah I have considered an option like that, although I was weary as to when I, for example, would have 5 labels. I'm not sure how bootstrap would react with a `col-sm-2.4` class...

Comment: you will not get `2.4` since `Count` is an integer it will be 2.

Comment: I would still get the problem of it only filling 10 columns though, leaving 2 still missing.

Comment: More logic will be required for the count of 5 but that shouldn't bloat your code too much...

Comment: @DannyGoodall I was already updating my answer to handle that. Anyways Now I am complete

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use the Bootstrap grid classes. Labels and inputs are inline elements, so you can center them like any bit of text. Just apply a wrapper div around all the labels and apply the `text-center` Bootstrap class.

```
<div class="text-center">
    foreach (string answer in Model.Answers)
    {
        <label class="PreviousAnswerLbl">
            @if (answer == Model.PreviousAnswer)
                {
                     <input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" checked="checked" /><span>@answer</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="@answer" /><span>@answer</span>
                }
        </label>
    }
</div>
```